# Div scaling to content when height is set to 100%

Tags: html, css

I have three nested divs, with the inner one having fixed height, the middle one intended to fill up the outer one, and the outer one accomodating a stuck-to-the-bottom footer. But the middle div seems to only be as high as the inner one, which I don't want.

I reduced the problem to the following, which I believe is a minimal example. I don't want to change the height properties of the outer or inner divs, since that will interfere with the rest of the layout. Is there a way to do what I want by just changing the middle div's properties?

Here's the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head> 

    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="middle">
                <div id="inner"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
html{height:100%;}
body{height:100%;}
#outer{height: auto; min-height: 100%;}
#middle{height: 100%;}
#inner{height:500px;}
```

You can check that the `#middle` div gets height 500 whereas I want it to fill the `#outer` div.

I'm a complete newbie to CSS, and almost all of the code is copied from different tutorials and/or trial and error. So please excuse me if I'm doing something blatantly wrong/stupid.

**Edit:** I don't understand why, but it seems removing the doctype declaration makes the issue go away. Hence I've changed the code samples to include the declaration.

Comment: did you try using firebug to see the css that applies to that div?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I tried using inspect element. It says the only style applied to it is `height: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was putting the 'body' and 'html' class to height: 100% (which does nothing). Instead I put your outer div to 100% height.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div {border:2px solid black;}
div div {border-color: blue;}
div div div {border-color: red;}
#outer{height: 100%; min-height: 100%;}
#middle{height: 100%;}
#inner{height:500px;}
</style>
</head> 

<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="middle">
            <div id="inner"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In case you couldn't work out how to get the footer in the mix, I've given you an example too:

```
<html>
    <head>
<style type="text/css">
div {border:2px solid black;}
div div {border-color: blue;}
div div div {border-color: red;}
#outer{height: 100%; min-height: 100%; position: relative;}
#middle{height: 100%;}
#inner{height:500px;}
#footer{height:100px;width:100%;position:absolute;bottom:0;}
</style>
    </head> 

    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="middle">
                <div id="inner"></div> 
            </div>
            <div id="footer">This is the footer</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now this is beyond my understanding of html/CSS. The only difference between your file and mine that makes the problem appear is that my html has a doctype declaration at the top. I'll make appropriate changes to the question to reflect this.

Comment: @ronno I wasn't supplying you the whole file, it was just an example lol. Added an example of having your footer in this layout for you.

Comment: @ronno Oh I don't think you noticed, I changed your CSS slightly. There is a difference, as I've written above the code example

Comment: What I meant was if I removed the doctype declaration from my page, the problem disappeared. And with your code, everything has height 500.

Comment: @ronno 500? It fills the height of the screen for me

Comment: If I exclude the DOCTYPE then both our codes work fine. Otherwise yours makes everything 500, mine makes the middle one 500 but the outer one filling. This is both on Chromium and Firefox.